# Java Pathfinding Lee Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, game, pathfinding

For my Pacman game i need to implement a pathfinding algorithm. I decide to do it with the Lee Algorithm, because in my opinion it's easier to understand than e.g. A* Star algorithm.
I tried to implement it as explained on Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm)

My output looks like this, O stands for Obstacle and 0 are the path:

```
Path exists
Shortest Path:
5 4
4 4
3 4
3 3
3 2
2 2
2 1
2 0
1 0
0 0

0 O 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 O 1 1 1 
0 0 0 O 1 1 1 
1 O 0 0 0 1 1 
1 O 1 O 0 1 1 
1 1 1 O 0 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Node.java

```
class Node {

private int x;
private int y;
private int value;

public Node(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Node(int x, int y, int value) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.value = value;
}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public boolean equals(Node n) {
    if (this.x == n.x && this.y == n.y) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.x + " " + this.y;
  }
}
```

LeeAlgorithm.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class LeeAlgorithm {

private final int matrixWidth = 7, matrixHeight = 7;
private int matrix[][] = new int[matrixWidth][matrixHeight];
private boolean matrixVisited[][] = new boolean[matrixWidth][matrixHeight];
private ArrayList<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
private final int MAXITERATIONS = 1000;
private final int OBSTACLE = -1;


/*
 find the shortest path between start and goal 

 */

public LeeAlgorithm() {
    matrix[4][1]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[4][1]=true;
    matrix[3][1]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[3][1]=true;
    matrix[2][3]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[2][3]=true;
    matrix[4][3]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[4][3]=true;
    matrix[5][3]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[5][3]=true;
    //matrix[1][0]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[1][0]=true; no path
    matrix[0][1]=OBSTACLE; matrixVisited[0][1]=true;
}

private ArrayList<Node> findPath(Node start, Node goal) {

    if (nodeList.isEmpty()) {
        nodeList.add(start);
        matrixVisited[start.getX()][start.getY()] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < MAXITERATIONS; i++) {

        nodeList = markNeighbors(nodeList, i);

        if (matrix[goal.getX()][goal.getY()] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Path exists");
            break;
        }

        if (i == MAXITERATIONS - 1) {
            System.out.println("No Path exists");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Node> pathList = backtraceFromGoal(goal, start);

    return pathList;
}


/*
 First step

  mark all unlabeled neighbors of points which are marked with i, with i+1
 */

private ArrayList<Node> markNeighbors(ArrayList<Node> neighborList, int iteration) {

    ArrayList<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for (Node node : neighborList) {

        if (node.getY() + 1 < matrix.length && matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1] == false) {

            Node node1 = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() + 1);
            neighbors.add(node1);
            matrix[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1] = iteration;
            matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1] = true;
        }

        if (node.getY() >= 1 && matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() - 1] == false) {

            Node node2 = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() - 1);
            neighbors.add(node2);
            matrix[node.getX()][node.getY() - 1] = iteration;
            matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() - 1] = true;
        }

        if (node.getX() + 1 < matrix.length && matrixVisited[node.getX() + 1][node.getY()] == false) {

            Node node3 = new Node(node.getX() + 1, node.getY());
            neighbors.add(node3);
            matrix[node.getX() + 1][node.getY()] = iteration;
            matrixVisited[node.getX() + 1][node.getY()] = true;
        }

        if (node.getX() >= 1 && matrixVisited[node.getX() - 1][node.getY()] == false) {

            Node node4 = new Node(node.getX()-1, node.getY() );
            neighbors.add(node4);
            matrix[node.getX() - 1][node.getY()] = iteration;
            matrixVisited[node.getX() - 1][node.getY()] = true;
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}

/*
 Second step

  from goal Node go to next node that has a lower mark than the current node
  add this node to path until start Node is reached
 */

private ArrayList<Node> backtraceFromGoal(Node fromGoal, Node toStart) {

    ArrayList<Node> pathList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    pathList.add(fromGoal);
    Node currentNode = null;

    while (!pathList.get(pathList.size() - 1).equals(toStart)) {

        currentNode = pathList.get(pathList.size() - 1);
        Node n = getNeighbor(currentNode);
        pathList.add(n);
        n = currentNode;
    }
    return pathList;
}

/*
  get Neighbor of node with smallest matrix value, todo shuffle
 */

private Node getNeighbor(Node node) {

    ArrayList<Node> possibleNeighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();

    if (node.getY() + 1 < matrix.length && matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1] == true &&
            matrix[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1]!=OBSTACLE) {

        Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() + 1, matrix[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1]);
        possibleNeighbors.add(n);
    }

    if (node.getY() >= 1 && matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() - 1] == true &&
            matrix[node.getX()][node.getY() -1 ]!=OBSTACLE) {

        Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() - 1, matrix[node.getX()][node.getY() - 1]);
        possibleNeighbors.add(n);
    }

    if (node.getX() + 1 < matrix.length && matrixVisited[node.getX() + 1][node.getY()] == true &&
            matrix[node.getX() + 1][node.getY()]!=OBSTACLE) {

        Node n = new Node(node.getX() + 1, node.getY(), matrix[node.getX() + 1][node.getY()]);
        possibleNeighbors.add(n);
    }

    if (node.getX() >= 1 && matrixVisited[node.getX() - 1][node.getY()] == true &&
            matrix[node.getX() - 1][node.getY()]!=OBSTACLE) {

        Node n = new Node(node.getX() - 1, node.getY(), matrix[node.getX() - 1][node.getY()]);
        possibleNeighbors.add(n);
    }

    Collections.sort(possibleNeighbors, new Comparator<Node>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Node first, Node second) {
            return first.getValue() - second.getValue();
        }
    });

    Node n = possibleNeighbors.remove(0);

    return n;
}

private void printSolution(ArrayList<Node> output) {

    System.out.println("Shortest Path:");
    for (Node n : output) {
        int x=n.getX();
        int y=n.getY();
        System.out.println(n.toString());
        matrix[x][y]=0;
    }

    System.out.println("");

   for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

            if(matrix[i][j]!=0 && matrix[i][j]!=OBSTACLE) {
                matrix[i][j]=1;                 
            }

            if(matrixVisited[i][j]==false) {
                matrix[i][j]=1;
            }

            if(matrix[i][j]==OBSTACLE) {
                System.out.print("O ");
            }

            else {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
            }
         }
        System.out.println("");
    }               
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LeeAlgorithm l = new LeeAlgorithm();
    ArrayList<Node> output = l.findPath(new Node(0, 0), new Node(5, 4));

    l.printSolution(output);

 } 
}
```

Any Suggestions and improvements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A standard trick to avoid testing for `node.getY() + 1 < matrix.length` etc is to add a border to your matrix, and initialize all nodes on the border to visited. The test reduces to just `matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1] == false`. This can also be shortened to `!matrixVisited[node.getX()][node.getY() + 1]`.
- The `Node`'s public getters and setters only add clutter to the code. Rather make the fields themselves `public`.

  Correct me if I am wrong, `setValue` is never called.
- DRY. Instead of spelling out all four neighbors, create a helper `delta` array of nodes `[(-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 0)]`, and iterate over it, computing the neighbor as

  ```
          neighbor.x = node.x + delta[i].x;
          neighbor.y = node.y + delta[i].y;
          etc;
  ```
- `MAX_ITERATION` looks artificial. The loop shall end (with failure) if there is no more nodes to mark. In other words, fail when the `nodeList.size()` become zero.
- The semantics of `nodeList, markNeighbors(), neighborList, neighbors` is very unclear. I recommend to stick with the Lee algorithm's metaphor, and use names like `waveFront, propagateWave()` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips. I have improved my program.